# Unique headerValue and expandedValue for ExpansionPanelRadio

Tags: list, flutter, class, expansion

How to add unique value to each expandable tile to make the FAQ look like this?

[image: FAQ Example]

Took my code from this link: https://medium.com/aubergine-solutions/how-to-create-expansion-panel-list-in-flutter-2fba574366e8

I want to add my own unique headerValue and expandedValue and not let it just take up a standard number like

```
 headerValue: 'Book $index',
      expandedValue: 'Details for Book $index goes here'
```

I'll probably be using this class and not theirs:

```
class FAQ {
  FAQ({
    this.id,
    this.expandedValue,
    this.headerValue,
  });

  int id;
  String expandedValue;
  String headerValue;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your custom class which can return a list of your questions. In your `Item` class you need to define functions `Item.fromJson(dynamic json)` which will return you `Map` or your items. Then you can create one more function where you will pass your actual data to your class `Item` and it will return you `Map` so you can use in your widgets.

Here is the full code and working

```
  class Item {
  final String id;
  final String expandedValue;
  final String headerValue;
  Item(
    this.id,
    this.expandedValue,
    this.headerValue,
  );

  factory Item.fromJson(dynamic json) {
    return Item(
        "${json['id']}", "${json['expandedValue']}", "${json['headerValue']}");
  }
}

var mylist = [
  {"id": "1", "headerValue": "question 1", "expandedValue": "answer 1"},
  {"id": "2", "headerValue": "question 2", "expandedValue": "answer 2"}
];

getFeedbackList() {
  return mylist.map((json) => Item.fromJson(json)).toList();
}

class ExpansionItems extends StatefulWidget {
  const ExpansionItems({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ExpansionItems> createState() => _ExpansionItemsState();
}

class _ExpansionItemsState extends State<ExpansionItems> {
  final List<Item> _data = getFeedbackList();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(_data);
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Container(
        child: _buildPanel(),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildPanel() {
    return ExpansionPanelList.radio(
      initialOpenPanelValue: 2,
      children: _data.map<ExpansionPanelRadio>(
        (Item item) {
          return ExpansionPanelRadio(
            value: item.id,
            headerBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool isExpanded) {
              return ListTile(
                title: Text(item.headerValue),
              );
            },
            body: ListTile(
              title: Text(item.expandedValue),
            ),
          );
        },
      ).toList(),
    );
  }
}
```

You can try above code [here](https://dartpad.dev/0ead9e68703317f43a39dcd2c9ffd4e4?null_safety=true)

Comment: Thanks Chirag. This is exactly what I was looking for. By any chance, you know how to solve the timer countdown?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67825718/how-to-use-timer-to-countdown-to-a-certain-time-of-the-day